# Adding multiple images randomly with click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a small game on my website to experiment with JavaScript that adds hotdogs to a bowl in random positions (building a pyramid shaped pile then covering the page).

But I'm not sure how to implement it. 10 hotdogs should go in the bowl, then 50 more should spill onto the 'game board,' then after that they would randomly cover the webpage. Right now I'm just wondering how to add the image elements `onclick` in random orientations using only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript if possible. Code shown below:

```
HTML:
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Game</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|IBM+Plex+Sans:100,200,300i,500|Lato:300,300i,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/game.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Title Section-->
        <h1>FEED THE PUP</h1>
        <p>Tap to give the dog some food, go for a high score or something!</p>

        <!-- Game Section-->
        <div id = 'gameSpace'>
            <img id = 'dog' src="./resources/images/png/dog.png" alt="">
            <img id = 'dogBowl' src="./resources/images/png/dogBowl.png" alt="">
            <img class = 'hotdog' src="./resources/images/png/hot-dog.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class = 'scoreBoard'>
            <p>SCORE:</p>
            <p id = 'gameScore'>0</p>
        </div>

        <div class = 'thanks'>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Dog icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/photo3idea-studio" title="photo3idea_studio">photo3idea_studio</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Dog bowl icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/good-ware" title="Good Ware">Good Ware</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Hotdog icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
        </div>

        <script  src="game.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
CSS:
body {
    background-color: #C5F4E0;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    height: fit-content;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Bungee';
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-shadow: #232835 0px 3px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #232835;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0rem;
}

#gameSpace {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: #232835 2px ridge;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 25rem;
    margin: 0rem auto;
    background-color: #F0F5F2;
    align-items: flex-end;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dog {
    max-width: 10rem;
    max-height: 10rem;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: baseline;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

#dogBowl {
    max-width: 8rem;
    max-height: 8rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.hotdog {
    display: none;
}

.scoreBoard {
    display: flex;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 20rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    background-color: #232835;
    border: #232835 1px ridge;
    align-items: center;
    color: #F0F5F2;
}

.scoreBoard p {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: fit-content;
    padding-left: .5rem;
    margin: 0rem 0rem;
    color: #F0F5F2;
}

#gameScore {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

/* THANKS SECTION */
.thanks {
    height: 3rem;
    width: auto;
}

.attribute {
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    margin: 0rem auto;
}

/* MEDIA SECTION */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #gameSpace {
        width: 75%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

```
JavaScript:
let food = 0;

function upDog() {
    food++;
    document.getElementById("gameScore").innerHTML = food;
}

gameSpace.onclick = upDog;
```

Comment: You may want to add (instead of updating, affecting) an image (instead of the number `food` or ) to your element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, @drewemerine!

> Right now I'm just wondering how to add the image elements onclick in random orientations using only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript if possible.

Instead of having an initial hotdog image in the HTML, I created a JavaScript function called `makeHotDog()` to create a hotdog image on the fly. It utilizes another function which just spits out random coordinates for the image. I hope this helps you out!

```js
let food = 0;
let gameSpace = document.getElementById("gameSpace");

function getRandomPosition(element) {
  let x = gameSpace.offsetHeight-element.clientHeight;
  let y = gameSpace.offsetWidth-element.clientWidth;
  let randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
  let randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
  return [randomX,randomY];
}

function makeHotDog() {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  let xy = getRandomPosition(img);
  img.setAttribute("src", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515875976234-9d59c3ef288d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
  img.setAttribute("class", "hotdog");
  gameSpace.appendChild(img);
  img.style.top = xy[0] + 'px';
  img.style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
}

function upDog() {
  food++;
  document.getElementById("gameScore").innerHTML = food;  
  makeHotDog();
}

gameSpace.onclick = upDog;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #C5F4E0;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    height: fit-content;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Bungee';
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-shadow: #232835 0px 3px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #232835;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0rem;
}

#gameSpace {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: #232835 2px ridge;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 25rem;
    margin: 0rem auto;
    background-color: #F0F5F2;
    align-items: flex-end;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#dog {
    max-width: 10rem;
    max-height: 10rem;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: baseline;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

#dogBowl {
    max-width: 8rem;
    max-height: 8rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.hotdog {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
}

.scoreBoard {
    display: flex;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 20rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    background-color: #232835;
    border: #232835 1px ridge;
    align-items: center;
    color: #F0F5F2;
}

.scoreBoard p {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: fit-content;
    padding-left: .5rem;
    margin: 0rem 0rem;
    color: #F0F5F2;
}

#gameScore {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

/* THANKS SECTION */
.thanks {
    height: 3rem;
    width: auto;
}

.attribute {
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    margin: 0rem auto;
}

/* MEDIA SECTION */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #gameSpace {
        width: 75%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Game</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|IBM+Plex+Sans:100,200,300i,500|Lato:300,300i,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/game.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Title Section-->
        <h1>FEED THE PUP</h1>
        <p>Tap to give the dog some food, go for a high score or something!</p>

        <!-- Game Section-->
        <div id = 'gameSpace'>
            <img id = 'dog' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=660&q=80" alt="">
            <img id = 'dogBowl' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510035618584-c442b241abe7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=80" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class = 'scoreBoard'>
            <p>SCORE:</p>
            <p id = 'gameScore'>0</p>
        </div>

        <div class = 'thanks'>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Dog icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/photo3idea-studio" title="photo3idea_studio">photo3idea_studio</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Dog bowl icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/good-ware" title="Good Ware">Good Ware</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
            <p class = 'attribute'>Hotdog icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a></p>
        </div>

        <script  src="game.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works super well! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @drewemerine Awesome! If this answer helped you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the solution.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I got upvoting confused with marking a solution. Thanks again for the help. Cheers.